# How to use mock to test a getter used for caching?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

In the following class the property `wheels` has a cached value.

```py
import time
class Car:
    @property
    def wheels(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_wheels'):
            self._count_wheels()
        return self._wheels

    def _count_wheels(self):
        time.sleep(10)  # simulate a long calculation
        self._wheels = 4


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Car()
    print(c.wheels)  # calls _count_wheels() once
    print(c.wheels)  # no calls to _count_wheels()
```

I want to test that the first call to `c.wheels` calls once the method `_count_wheels()`; while the second call to `c.wheels` doesn't call the method `_count_wheels()`
I'd like to use *unittest.mock*

Comment: You NEED to use unittest.mock or a simpler solution fit your needs?

Comment: Go with the simpler solution!

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to mock the object yourself:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    count = 0    
    to_mock = Car._count_wheels
    def mocked(self):
        global count
        count +=1
        if count>1:
            raise ValueError("Called twice")
        to_mock(self)        

    Car._count_wheels = mocked
    c = Car()
    print(c.wheels)  # calls _count_wheels() once
    try:
        print(c.wheels)  # no calls to _count_wheels()
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
```

You can try it with this modified `Car` class:

```
class Car:
    @property
    def wheels(self):
        #if not hasattr(self, '_wheels'):
        self._count_wheels()
        return self._wheels

    def _count_wheels(self):
        #time.sleep(10)  # simulate a long calculation
        self._wheels = 4
```

And you will see it raises the exception. Since python is so dynamic this approach is always valid and sometimes is very useful, but of course you can use a third party tool as well ;)

Comment: This is a solution that more or less popped into my mind at first. For sure this works and it is simple. But I've got the feeling that mocking libraries (which I don't know too much about) are perfect for such situations, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I think the main reason of the mocking libraries to exist are  non-dynamic languages like `Java`, `C++`, etc. They just do what is very easy of doing in Python. But of course it's a matter of taste, I like to manually mock my objects but as I said you can use anything you like if it fits better with your own way of coding ;)